# Docker containers lose internet connection until container restart

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

Some of my docker containers keep losing internet connection periodically. With some, the problem does not seem to occur at all, and with others, it happens intermittently where some are more susceptible to the issue then others. Important to note that the internet connection on the host server (HP Proliant Gen 10 machine running Ubuntu) works just fine and in order to restore the internet connection to the container, I simply have to restart the container itself and not the entire docker daemon. Not a huge problem, but certainly annoying. Any ideas as to how I can go about resolving this?

Comment: What kind of docker networks do you use? Do you have SELinux or similar tools installed on the host machine?

Comment: I'm quite new to docker so not sure how to check that? I just installed docker out of the box on Ubuntu linux.no additional tools installed

Comment: @BastianKlein, any more advice that you can provide as to what I can check? as mentioned, it's a stock standard docker installation with no added docker tools installed (apart from portainer which runs in it's own container)

Comment: you can use restart policy of docker, for more info [Docker Restart Concept](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#:~:text=Docker%20provides%20restart%20policies%20to,started%20in%20the%20correct%20order.)

Comment: I would recommend you to use this flag `--restart=unless-stopped` if you are running it directly. and if you are using docker-compose, in compose.yml file there is `restart: unless-stopped` property

Answer (score 0):

you can use restart policy of docker, for more info [Docker Restart Concept](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#:%7E:text=Docker%20provides%20restart%20policies%20to,started%20in%20the%20correct%20order.). I would recommend you to use this flag `--restart=unless-stopped` if you are running it directly. and if you are using docker-compose, in compose.yml file there is `restart: unless-stopped` property

Comment: All docker containers use --restart=unless-stopped. Except for Portainer which as part of it's installation sets --restart=always. Incidentally, I have never had issues with Portainer specifically.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an assumption, does your Ubuntu build have a static ip address set on the server? Or is it set to automatically configure all network interfaces by DHCP via the `dhcpcd` daemon ?

It maybe that your Ubuntu solution is set to automatically configure all network interfaces periodically and that loss of dynamic ip address causes your containers to lose internet connection, as they may have cached the host ip address. Thus, when the host dynamically updates the assigned ip address, the docker can no longer connect.

If it is dynamic, maybe suggest set up a static ip and see how you go ?

Update your `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` or `/etc/dhcpd.conf` to add the static ip

Comment: Yes, a static IP has been assigned to the host.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I found containers that were losing connection with other containers were because OpenVPN connection timed-out - OpenVPN then resets, causing the other containers (that depend on OpenVPN) to lose the interfaces en0 and tun0.
I made a janky script to find this abnormality.

```
interface=sudo docker ps | grep sonarr | awk '{print  $1 " bash"}' | xargs bash -c 'sudo docker exec $0 netstat' | awk '/(utun0:|en0)/ {print $1}'
if ["$interface" = ""]; then
    cd /volume1/docker; docker-compose stop; sleep 10; docker-compose start;
fi
```